# Volume material to Geometry Nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

How to apply the volume material to Geometry Nodes correctly?

[image]

Comment: I think it only works with cycles

Answer (score 1):

You can use Volume Cube for that, but it comes in 3.3 version:

[image]